# Can't set root MySQL password to null

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.7

When installing mysql, I didn't put anything in the root password fields, but when I ran `mysql -u root` I still got `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

I started mysql up in safe mode without the grant tables, `sudo mysql_safe --skip-grant-tables &`, then jumped in with `mysql -u root` without a problem.

Then I did `use mysql; update user set authentication_string=null where user='root';` and I got:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Anyone have any insight on why the password isn't updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the plugin to `mysql_native_password`, so the password reset part looks like this:

```
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step by step it will be like this

Stop the MySQL Server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld configuration.

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root.

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Comment: Take a look at the last few lines of output. The last line should say `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` doesn't do anything here because nothing was changed. Also, in mysql 5.7 the `password` field was replaced with `authentication_string`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not look the "0 rows affected". Select the user table and see the exist root user in the table